# how can i solve this "Cannot subscript a value of type `[[String]]` with an index of type `UInt32`"

Tags: swift, xcode9

i'm having a problem about this `UInt32` thing,
the "answer" in my button is having an error about this "Cannot subscript a value of type `[[String]]` with an index of type `UInt32`"

```
let answers = [["1. After the exam, I felt too exhausted and famished to eat my foods.","2. I could eat a horse, I am a famish now.","3. I famished my stomach next time you treat me to a meal out.","4. I will bring lots of pizza, that's famish."],["Would","Has to","Must","Could"]]  

var rightanswerplacement:UInt32 = 0


 rightanswerplacement = arc4random_uniform(2)+1
        var button:UIButton = UIButton()

        var x = 1

        for i in 1...3{

                button = view.viewWithTag(i) as! UIButton

            if (i == Int(rightanswerplacement)){
                button.setTitle(answers[rightanswerplacement][0], for: UIControlState.normal)

            }
            else{
                button.setTitle(answers[rightanswerplacement][x], for: UIControlState.normal)
                x = 2
            }

            currentquestions += 1

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **Int** for subscripts.

**Note: I removed the views to test the correctness of Int.**

```
let answers = [["1. After the exam, I felt too exhausted and famished to eat my foods.","2. I could eat a horse, I am a famish now.","3. I famished my stomach next time you treat me to a meal out.","4. I will bring lots of pizza, that's famish."],["Would","Has to","Must","Could"]]

var rightanswerplacement: Int = 0
rightanswerplacement = Int(arc4random_uniform(2)) + 1
var x = 1
for i in 1...3 {
    if (i == Int(rightanswerplacement)) {
        print(answers[rightanswerplacement][0])
    } else {
        print(answers[rightanswerplacement][x])
        x = 2
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Would
Has to
Must
```

Comment: it said it's obsolete the "+"

Comment: @Barney: + works fine and I tested it. You can verify in playground!

Comment: Fixed! your answer helped i just mistyped it thank you so much!